# Split vector with letters and numbers at the letters, into a list

Tags: r

I have a character vector with letters and numbers:

```
c("A", "1", "2", "3",   "B", "4", "5",   "D", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")
```

I would like to transform this vector into list. The names of the list elements are the letters in the vector. The values in each list element are the numbers in the vector, which come in blocks between letters:

```
list(A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c(4, 5), ...)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's one way.  Nothing fancy, but it gets the job done.

```
x <- c("A","1","2","3","B","4","5","D","6","7","8","9","10")
y <- cumsum( grepl("[[:alpha:]]", x) )
z <- list()
for(i in unique(y)) z[[x[y==i][1]]] <- as.numeric(x[y==i][-1])
z
# $A
# [1] 1 2 3
#
# $B
# [1] 4 5
#
# $D
# [1]  6  7  8  9 10

# UPDATE: Trying to be a bit more "fancy"
a <- grepl("[[:alpha:]]", x)
b <- factor(cumsum(a), labels=x[a])
c <- lapply(split(x,b), function(x) as.numeric(x[-1]))
```

Comment: your threshold for fancy must be higher than mine, nice work!

Comment: I wish I could give this +100. That is a very clever use of `cumsum` on a logical vector---I can see many applications for it in some of my own code.

Comment: Thanks everyone. @Chase: see my update for my "fancy threshold".  @Sharpie: you could always offer a 100 reputation bounty on the question and award it to me. :-P

Comment: @Joshua : you actually called the list `c`? tss tss tss... ;)

Comment: @Joshua that is a very nice solution indeed.

Comment: @Wojciech if @Joshua's answer solves your problem, please accept it via the big tick on the left.