# Splitting a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector x made up of "Y" and "N".

```
> x
 [1] Y N N N N N N N N N N Y N N N N
```

I would like to split this into

```
> x1
 [1] Y N N N N N N N N N N
```

and

```
> x2
 [1] Y N N N N
```

These vectors always start with a "Y" and take in all "N"s before the next "Y". Suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Possibly related: [transform vector into list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174144/transform-vector-into-list)

Answer (score 7):

You can use a combination of `cumsum` and `split` to do this with a one-liner:

```
x <- c("Y","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","Y","N","N","N","N")
v <- split(x,paste("x",cumsum(x=="Y"),sep=""))
```

Comment: +1 `split()` is a great function to get to know and make friends with :)

Answer (score 3):

There are surely better ways, but:

```
tst<-c("Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N")
starts<-which(tst=="Y") #where are the "Y"
ends<-c(starts[-1]-1, length(tst)) #pos before each "Y""
lapply(seq_along(starts), function(i){tst[(starts[i]):(ends[i])]}) #parts from each start till each end
```

Answer (score 3):

Collapse into one string, then split on the "Y"s.

```
x <- c("Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N")
y <- paste(x, collapse = "")
z <- paste("Y", strsplit(pn, "Y")[[1]], sep = "")[-1]
z
```

Or using run length encoding.

```
n <- rle(x)$lengths[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
lapply(n, function(i) paste("Y", rep.int("N", i), sep = "", collapse = ""))
```

(This give you a list rather than a vector.  Use `unlist` if this isn't what you want.)